# Finding Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of 3 by 3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of:
>   $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 
> 4 & 0 & -9 \\
> 9 & -5 & -8\\
> 0 & 0 &-5 
> \end{pmatrix}$$

$$A=\begin{vmatrix} 
4-\lambda & 0 & -9 \\
9 & -5-\lambda & -8\\
0 & 0 &-5-\lambda 
\end{vmatrix}=(-5-\lambda)\begin{vmatrix} 
4-\lambda & 0  \\
9 & -5-\lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}=(-5-\lambda)^2(4-\lambda)$$

So $\lambda_{1}=-5$ and $\lambda_{2}=4$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
4+5 & 0 & -9 \\
9 & -5+5 & -8\\
0 & 0 &-5+5 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
9 & 0 & -9 \\
9 & 0 & -8\\
0 & 0 &0 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 &0 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 &0 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 &1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

So the eigenvectors of $\lambda_{1}=-5$ are :
$$\{\begin{pmatrix} 
0  \\
1 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}\}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
4-4 & 0 & -9 \\
9 & -5-4 & -8\\
0 & 0 &-5-4 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & -9 \\
9 & -9 & -8\\
0 & 0 &-9 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 &0 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -1 &0  \\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

So the eigenvectors of $\lambda_{2}=4$ are :
$$\{\begin{pmatrix} 
1  \\
1 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}\,\begin{pmatrix} 
0 \\
0\\
1 
\end{pmatrix}\}$$

Where did I get it wrong? How can it be that I got a matrix with a rank of $2$ but just $1$ solution?

Even more odd here are some solutions from calculators that give diffreant results:
http://bit.ly/2c1J7oq

http://bit.ly/2be8lKf

Comment: Your eigenvectors appear to be correct ( (0,1,0) for -5 and (1,1,0) for -4). What do you mean by just 1 solution though?

Comment: @Isomorphism I got a rank of $2$ and a null space of $2$ vectors, that can not be

Comment: Where are you calculating the nullspace? Because a $3x3$ rank 2 matrix must have a 1 dimensional nullspace as the rank-nullity theorem states (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)

Comment: @JosuEtxezarretaMartinez I have edited the qeustion (Swap the calculation by mistake) the eigenvectors are the basis of the null space, and in the case of the eigenvalue 4 I have  2 vectors and I need to get just 1

Comment: The eigenvectors are not the basis of the nullspace, the eigenvectors satisfy $A\nu = \lambda\nu$, while the basis of the kernel must satisfy $A\nu=0$, so I have not understood what you said in the last comment or you are confused with the meaning of the eigenvectors.

Comment: @JosuEtxezarretaMartinez the eigenvectors of a an eigenvalue let say $\lambda$ is the nullspace of the matrix $A-\lambda I$

Comment: Ok, then, the eigenvector $\nu = (0,0,1)$ is not an eigenvector for $\lambda =4$ as it does not fulfill $(A-\lambda I)\nu=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is here ($\lambda=4$): you have to solve $$I) x_1 + -x_2 + 0 = 0$$ 
$$II) 0 + 0 + 0 = 0$$
$$III) 0 + 0 + x_3 = 0$$
therefore $x_1=x_2, x_3=0$
and
$$ker 
\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} = $$ 
$$\{\begin{pmatrix}
        1  \\
        1  \\
        0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}\}$$